# React post method 404 to Public Url

Tags: reactjs

I have created a React application, i am trying to secure a param which is sent as a initial query parameter in url, is there a way for the first public url request with post method?

```
http://localhost:3000/  GET i can download content
http://localhost:3000/  POST i got 404 error
```

(i am trying to find a way to get content like GET method request)

I hope my question is clear enough, i am looking forward to hearing your ideas,